# Standard HTTP request header for preview requests

Tags: http, http-headers

Is there a standard HTTP request header or other request indicator for when a device makes a request in order to show a preview vs. full display?

The use case for this is things like password reset and other use-once links that you want invalidated after first access.  Mobile phone preview ruins this model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET` requests should be, by definition, *safe*, meaning that they don't result in a state change on the server. Therefore, a `GET` request should never invalidate anything. And since they are also *idempotent*, there's no difference between doing one `GET` or a hundred.

To answer your question, then, there's no distinction in HTTP between a "preview" `GET` and a "full display" `GET`.

Most password reset mechanisms that I'm familiar with use `POST` or `PUT` to change state on the server, and that's not something that will be triggered by any link preview.

Comment: Absolutely. If you have a GETable resource, and GETting it twice is a problem, the problem is on your side.

Comment: Good point.  I was attempting to optimize my token invalidator code by detecting a non-preview display of the page in one place instead of in all the possible places where it indicates as user has taken action (the POSTs).  More of a code maintenance/usage simplification (this token system is also used for other purposes like validating emails and phone numbers).  But not only will handling it in the actual POSTs be more compliant, it will likely in the long run be a more solid design that more robustly handles new situations.

Comment: I'm not opposed to violating a standard in a well thought out application where the standard opposes the best choice forward (I used to use goto to a single exit point in a routine before try/finally was available -- it eliminated many convoluted backflips in code and the resulting code was much less complex, more readable, and more maintainable) but this instance was me not thinking through it and perhaps a bit of laziness.